# Looking up for multiple results

Tags: mysql

```
StudentProfile
-studentid

Registration
-registrationid
-studentid(foreign key to StudentProfile)

RegistrationSchedule
-regscheduleid(is not a primary key,, is not unique,,can have a lot of instances)
-registrationdid(foreign key to registration)
-scheduleid

Schedules
-scheduleid
```

please keep in mind that there is no regscheduleid in schedules table
 i'v tried inner joining them all but only on result comes up
how can i get all the schedules of that student

Comment: Please show us the SQL statement you are using.

Comment: Can you show the query you've tried that you think should work?

Comment: What do you want the results to look like?

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all the information, from student's profile, to schedule details.

```
SELECT t.StudentID, s.ScheduleID
FROM StudentProfile t JOIN Registration r
    ON t.studentid = r.studentid
  JOIN RegistrationSchedule rs 
    ON r.registrationid = rs.registrationdid
  JOIN Schedules s ON rs.scheduleid = s.scheduleid
```

Remove the tables you do not need in the query.

If you want to filter for a specific student, add `WHERE t.studentid = 1234`.

Comment: You stated in the question studentid **(foreign key to StudentProfile**)! You gotta tell us what the "desired result" is *we are not mind readers*

Comment: sir this only shows 1 value.....it doesn't show other schedules of the specific student

Comment: @user623473 Then your tables are not populated correctly... Again, not something we can do for you.